# How to checkout git submodule with different deploy key in declarative pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-submodules

I have a project hosted in a Enterprise GitHub instance. The project references a sub module in the same instance.

- For accessing the main project, I configured the "DeployKey_1" in Github repository.
- For accessing the submodule project, I configured the "DeployKey_2" in Github repository.

Note: I can't use the same deploy key on GitHub Enterprise: [Key Already in Use](https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-key-already-in-use)

The Jenkins Job is defined as Multibranch pipeline and I use the `checkout` command in the Jenkinsfile:

```
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: scm.branches,
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
    extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: false, recursiveSubmodules: true, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]],
    userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
])
```

I tried both option: Set `parentCredentials: true` and `parentCredentials: false`, but both are resulting in this error when executing the job:

> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git submodule update --init
>   --recursive my-submodule" returned status code 1: stdout:  stderr: Cloning into
>   '/private/tmp/workspace/project_develop/my-submodule'...
>   git@github.mycompany.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists. fatal: clone of
>   'git@github.mycompany.de:myorga/my-submodule.git'
>   into submodule path
>   '/private/tmp/workspace/project_develop/my-submodule'
>   failed Failed to clone 'my-submodule'. Retry scheduled Cloning
>   into
>   '/private/tmp/workspace/project_develop/my-submodule'...
>   git@github.mycompany.de: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Both deploy keys are available on Jenkins. So, how can I checkout the submodules? How can I tell the `checkout` command to use a specific `credentials-id` when checking out the submodule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's to far down to git configuration, and too much of of edge use case for SCM to support that.

As for options with GitSCM there `submoduleCfg`, but it only allows you to do as much as set the name and branch of the submodule.

```
package hudson.plugins.git;

public class SubmoduleConfig implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String   submoduleName;
    String[] branches;
```

If you would move from using a key to credentials, then you could update your submodule configuration with hardcoded user/password.

```
git submodule init
git config submodule.my_submodule.url "https://username:password@url/my_submodule.git"
git submodule update
```

Comment: Ok, I hoped it was a more common use case and already provided by `checkout`. I had the same look at `SubmoduleConfig`. It would be right place to make change, I guess.

Comment: @Christopher it's funny that you edited my answer instead of commenting it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it's more easier for other people to see the solution right in the answer instead of picking it from the comments. :) Again thanks for your help here!

Comment: Glad to help, if the solution works do you mind accepting the answer?